# XSL - Checking more than one argument with select

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSL/XML, I looked up some answers similar to my heading but was unable to resolve my problem. I use a software to read PDF files and generate an XML with needed data. Then I use an XSL to structure the XML to fit a data format which is required by another system which add the extracted data to a database.

My XML (Part which matters to this question)

```xml
    <LineItemRow ID="6" FromPage="2">
          <Fields>
            <Field ID="123a66a4876d4f53bf87ac95dd623c67" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Heat (M)">
              <Value>40331</Value>
              <OcrExtractedValue T="40331 HEB100 FL L P 410 529 29" X="224" Y="997" H="15" W="850" L="27" C="100">
                <Keyword T="40331 " X="224" Y="997" H="15" W="70" L="27" C="100" />
              </OcrExtractedValue>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="8ff4d8bbde2b45039766a58952a040ae" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Ort">
              <Value>FL</Value>
              <OcrExtractedValue T="40331 HEB100 FL L P 410 529 29" X="224" Y="997" H="15" W="850" L="27" C="100">
                <Keyword T="FL " X="636" Y="998" H="14" W="27" L="27" C="100" />
              </OcrExtractedValue>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="1fd972224fd64c3aad82812a3a951ced" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Tensile - ReH">
              <Value>410</Value>
              <OcrExtractedValue T="40331 HEB100 FL L P 410 529 29" X="224" Y="997" H="15" W="850" L="27" C="100">
                <Keyword T="410 529 29 " X="824" Y="997" H="15" W="105" L="27" C="100" />
              </OcrExtractedValue>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="485dc23c9f35440e8d4683012b0d6b14" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Tensile - Rm">
              <Value>529</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="35c9bfa296e747d3b1249cd1a4804483" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Tensile - A5">
              <Value>29</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="23ffc002c972482284eb9c748e02dfe0" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Impact - Temp">
              <Value>-</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="bc4ab2575d0548c18fd0bd7ff41d0839" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Impact - 1">
              <Value>-</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="8219c9f6f2f248f6872f49497a3b5c1f" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Impact - 2">
              <Value>-</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="f6124a3e10c347fda48f8d39f7ee55cf" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Impact - 3">
              <Value>-</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="4a3493709a674350b22ec4bb2699a8b1" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Impact - MW">
              <Value>-</Value>
            </Field>
          </Fields>
        </LineItemRow>
```

My problem is I want to check 3 arguments in `select` which is not working for me I tried using `|` that also didn't work, the code with the `|` is below.

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="$container/BaseTypeObject/Metadata/LineItemRows/LineItemRow[Fields/Field[@Label = 'Heat (M)']]">
                <TestDataSet Type="3">
                    <xsl:attribute name="HeatID" select="Fields/Field[@Label = 'Heat (M)']/Value"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Fields/Field[@Label != 'Heat (M)'] | Fields/Field[@Label != 'Ort'] | Fields/Field[@Value != '-']">
                        <TestDataValue>
                            <xsl:attribute name="Qualifier" select="@Label"/>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="@Label = 'Tensile - Re'">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="Unit" select="'N/mm²'"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="@Label = 'Tensile - Rm'">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="Unit" select="'N/mm²'"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="@Label = 'Tensile - A5.65'">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="Unit" select="'%'"/>
                                </xsl:when>                             
                                <xsl:when test="@Label = 'Impact - Value 1'">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="Unit" select="'°C'"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="@Label = 'Impact - Value 2'">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="Unit" select="'J'"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="@Label = 'Impact - Value 3'">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="Unit" select="'J'"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="@Label = 'Impact - Temp'">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="Unit" select="'°C'"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:attribute name="PageNo">
                                <xsl:call-template name="GetPageNo">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="container" select="$container"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="lineitemrow" select="../.."/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <!--<xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="@Label = 'Hardness' and contains(Value,'-')">
                                    <xsl:variable name="min" select="number(substring-before(Value,'-'))"/>
                                    <xsl:variable name="max" select="number(substring-after(Value,'-'))"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="xs:decimal($min + (($max - $min) div 2))"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="xs:decimal(translate(Value,',','.'))"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>-->
                        </TestDataValue>
                    </xsl:for-each>
```

Out put,

```xml
        <TestDataSet Type="3" HeatID="40331">
            <TestDataValue Qualifier="Heat (M)" PageNo="2"/>
            <TestDataValue Qualifier="Ort" PageNo="2"/>
            <TestDataValue Qualifier="Tensile - ReH" PageNo="2"/>
            <TestDataValue Qualifier="Tensile - Rm" Unit="N/mm²" PageNo="2"/>
            <TestDataValue Qualifier="Tensile - A5" PageNo="2"/>
            <TestDataValue Qualifier="Impact - Temp" Unit="°C" PageNo="2"/>
            <TestDataValue Qualifier="Impact - 1" PageNo="2"/>
            <TestDataValue Qualifier="Impact - 2" PageNo="2"/>
            <TestDataValue Qualifier="Impact - 3" PageNo="2"/>
            <TestDataValue Qualifier="Impact - MW" PageNo="2"/>
        </TestDataSet>
```

As you can see I wanted to skip the labels Heat (M) and Ort also wanted to skip values which are `-` but out put was not what I wanted, it doesn't skip the unwanted once.

Then I read a bit more to find that it's better to use `not()` than `!=` so I changed the,`<xsl:for-each select="Fields/Field[@Label != 'Heat (M)'] | Fields/Field[@Label != 'Ort'] | Fields/Field[@Value != '-']">`

to

`<xsl:for-each select="not(Fields/Field[@Label = 'Heat (M)'] | Fields/Field[@Label = 'Ort'] | Fields/Field[@Value = '-'])">` which gave me an `Unexpected 'atomic' item` error.

I hope my question is clear enough and really hope some one could help me to solve this.

Comment: You need to use AND when combining negative predicates, not OR (or rather the UNION operator, like you do)..Or use a construct of `not(@Label=a or @Label=b or @Label=c)`. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Try spending an evening reading quickly through a book on XSLT to get an overview of the functionality available. You will find this is a far more effective way of learning the language than googling for problems similar to the one you are trying to solve.

Comment: Note also that `Value` is an element, not an attribute.

Comment: @MichaelKay thank you for your suggestion but the problem is when I read I fall a sleep. I'm more of a guy who learn things by doing.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I tried your suggestion and changed the line to this `<xsl:for-each select="not(@Label = 'Heat (M)' and @Label = 'Ort' and Value = '-')">`. It gave me an unexpected atomic item xs:boolean error on this line `<xsl:attribute name="Qualifier" select="@Label"/>` it highlights the `select="@Label"`

Comment: You need to do `<xsl:for-each select="Fields/Field[not(@Label = 'Heat (M)' or @Label = 'Ort' or Value = '-')]">`

Comment: You could also do `<xsl:for-each select="Fields/Field[@Label != 'Heat (M)' and @Label != 'Ort' and Value != '-']">` but this would give different results if the `Label` attribute was not present.

Comment: @TimC thank you, your suggestion worked. Learned another way how to do.